# Population average age decreases with births AND deaths (kind of)?

Tags: intuition

When a baby is born, it's easy to see the average age of the
population decreases.

Intuitively, therefore, when a person dies, the average age of the
population must increase to compensate.

However, this isn't always true. If the person who dies is above the
average (mean) age, the average age actually decreases (I'm ironically
omitting the math but can provide it on request).

This also applies to the median age: both births and above-average-age
deaths decrease the median.

The only way to increase the mean/median age is when a person dies
before reaching the mean/median age.

This seems really counter-intuitive. We expect most people to die 
AFTER they reach the mean/median population age.

Is there an intuitive way of understanding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to realize that the average age of the population always increases as the time flows!

So it's not really odd it decreases they way you describe. In fact it has to.

Comment: Of course! As long as the age decrease I describe is slower than the flow of time, the average age still increases. I will approve this answer as soon as stack lets me.